# Postfix Relaying Denied issues With ASSP

Tags: postfix, assp

I'm playing around with ASSP and postfix on a gateway server...
Basically all mail sent to the server will run to the gateway 10.0.0.1:25 (gateway.hostname.com), Hit ASSP, once processed will then be routed to localhost:10.0.0.1:25(same server postfix config handles the difference) and then postfix is setup to forward the mail out to the receiving server...

The issue I am having is that all mail routed to be sent to 10.0.0.2 (receiving server) does not get there, postfix give's me a relay not allowed error message...

Basically I want to forward all mail to the gateway once processed through to the 10.0.0.2 ip address, that server can respond if the recipient is invalid.

What do I need to change to allow this change?

Comment: Post your `main.cf` and `master.cf`.

Comment: I thought I was making a mistake with Postfix, turned out to be the local domain check in assp that was causing the issue. Thanks anyway @MichaelHampton :). Got it solved

Comment: Sounds like you got a solution. Please use the answer section below to share with future readers on how you figured and what eventually did the trick.